# Iterate through files in Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Datalake gen 1 with folder structure /Test/{currentyear}/**{Files}**

**{Files}** Example format
2020-07-29.csv
2020-07-30.csv
2020-07-31.csv

Every day one new file gets added to the folder.

I need to create ADF to load the files in the SQL server.
COnditions

1. When my ADF runs for the first time it needs to iterate all files and load into sql server
2. When ADF executing starting from second time( daily once) it needs to pick up only todays file and load into SQL server

Can anyone tell me how to design ADF with above conditions

Comment: Are you still there? I have post an answer just now. Please have a try.

Comment: @BowmanZhu Actually I would suggest using an event trigger, when a new blob created, then trigger the pipeline run. The new blob will be copy to the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This should be designed as two part.

> When my ADF runs for the first time it needs to iterate all files and
> load into sql server

You should create a temporary pipeline to acheieve this.(I think you know how to do this, so this part I will not talk about.)

> When ADF executing starting from second time( daily once) it needs to
> pick up only todays file and load into SQL server

So this needs you to create another pipeline which is continuous running.

Two points to acheive this:

**First,** trigger this pipeline by event trigger.(When the file is upload, trigger this pipeline.).

[image]

**Second,** filter the file by specific format:

[image]

For your requirement, the expression should be `@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}`.

On my side, I can do that successful. Please have a try on your side.